# list of dataframes to pdf

Tags: r, pdf

I have a function that produces a list of dataframes of different dimensions. I then want to create a pdf file which displays this output in order.

```
df1 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5),c("a","b","c","d","e"))
names(df1) <- c("no","letter")

df2 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5),c("a","b","c","d","e"),c("a","b","c","d","e"))
names(df2) <- c("no","letter1","letter2")

outputs <- list(df1,df2)
```

Is there a package that would be suitable for this or is it possible to use function such as `textplot` from the gdata package and then export to pdf?

Comment: Did you consider Sweave or knitr, or is that not an option?

Comment: I am aware of Sweave but not how to use it. knitr I do not know about and will look up. In what cases would that not be an option?

Comment: It probably wouldn't be an option if you don't want to use latex, as James already pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a minimal example using Sweave.

Create a file called test.Rnw containing:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

<<echo=F>>=
df1 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5),c("a","b","c","d","e"))
names(df1) <- c("no","letter")

df2 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5),c("a","b","c","d","e"),c("a","b","c","d","e"))
names(df2) <- c("no","letter1","letter2")

outputs <- list(df1,df2)

outputs
@

\end{document}
```

Then call from the command line:

```
R CMD R Sweave test.Rnw
pdflatex test.Rnw
```

Maybe that gets you started.

Comment: Note that you have to have a latex system installed

Answer (score 3):

One possible way is to plot a table of your data set (if you want to avoid TEX).

```
library(gridExtra)

pdf(file="file_name.pdf", width=20)
    grid.newpage()
    grid.draw(tableGrob(head(iris, 10), name="test"))
dev.off()
```

[image]

As always in R, there are a thousand ways to do things.

```
plot(...)
text(...,xtable(...))
```

The xtable function can also be used to improve the appearance in **jmsigner's** answer.

Answer (score 2):

Package gridExtra provide grid.table (and tableGrob for not immediate printing) which are very powerfull.
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/index.html
Here are some examples of grid.table :
http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:graphics-grid:table

```
    library(gridExtra)

    df1 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5),c("a","b","c","d","e"))
    names(df1) <- c("no","letter")

    df2 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5),c("a","b","c","d","e"),c("a","b","c","d","e"))
    names(df2) <- c("no","letter1","letter2")

    outputs <- list(df1,df2)
    pdf(file="filename.pdf")
    plyr::l_ply(outputs, grid.table)
    dev.off()
```

Comment: instead of the for loop try `plyr::l_ply(outputs, grid.table)`

Comment: @baptiste : thanks for the trick (and thank you very much for gridExtra; marrange() saves me hours of work)